# Is it critical for a SharePoint Developer to understand JavaScript, HTML, CSS, .NET/C# & SharePoint Front End Fundamentals in order to be proficient?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, development, sharepoint-addin, .net

I’m asking this because I’ve started a new job as a Jr. Software Developer.  Currently the role has a heavy emphasis on SharePoint development, as the company hasn’t ever had a developer assist with the management of their SharePoint, only Network Engineers. Currently running SP 2013, but will be migrating to 2016 and then 2019.

I’ve spent the past 2 weeks learning the OOTB functionality of SharePoint.  I’ve come to conclude that when faced with new business requirements, a truly proficient SharePoint Developer must be able to accurately decide when it is appropriate to when to:

A.) Simply employ OOTB functionality.

B.) Enhance OOTB functionality/styling with client side JavaScript, HTML, CSS and/or JQuery.

C.) Utilize SharePoint templates or C# code to create solutions.

Of course, there is much more to consider beyond what I’ve listed.  However, my question here is more of a poll to the readers as to whether or not I’m adopting the correct philosophy for this role. Hopefully your responses will be accompanied by years of experience as a SharePoint Developer.

Thanks